# Is it atomic operation when exchange std::atomic with itself?

Tags: c++, atomic, modulo, stdatomic

Will following code be executed atomically?

```
const int oldId = id.exchange((id.load()+1) % maxId);
```

Where `id` is `std::atomic<int>`, and `maxId` is some integer value.

I searched google and stackoverflow for `std::atomic` modulo increment. And I found some topics but I can't find clear answer how to do that properly.

In my case even better would be to use:

```
const int newId = id.exchange((++id) % maxId);
```

But I am still not sure if it will be executed atomically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not atomic, because the `load()` and the `exchange()` are separate operations, and nothing is preventing `id` from getting updated after the `load`, but before the `exchange`. In that case your `exchange` would write a value that has been calculated based on a stale input, so you end up with a missed update.

You can implement a modulo increment using a simple compare_exchange loop:

```cpp
int val = id.load();
int newVal = (val + 1) % maxId;
while (!id.compare_exchange_weak(val, newVal) {
  newVal = (val + 1) % maxId;
}
```

If the compare_exchange fails it performs a reload and populates `val` with the updated value. So we can re-calculate `newVal` and try again.

Edit:

The whole point of the compare-exchange-loop is to handle the case that between the load and the compare-exchange somebody might change `id`. The idea is to:

1. load the current value of `id`
2. calculate the new value
3. update `id` with our own value *if and only if* the value currently stored in `id` is the same one as we read in 1. If this is the case we are done, otherwise we restart at 1.

compare_exchange is allows us to perform the comparison and the conditional update in one atomic operation. The first argument to `compare_exchange` is the expected value (the one we use in our comparison). This value is passed *by reference*. So when the comparison fails, `compare_exchange` automatically reloads the current value and updates the provided variable (in our case `val`).

And since Peter Cordes pointed out correctly that this can be done in a do-while loop to avoid the code duplication, here it is:

```cpp
int val = id.load();
int newVal;
do {
  newVal = (val + 1) % maxId;
} while (!id.compare_exchange_weak(val, newVal);
```

Comment: A `do{}while()` loop is a good way to avoid repeating yourself, only writing the `(val+1) % maxID` once.  Another good alternative if `maxId` is always a power of 2 is to use `.fetch_add(1)` and have readers do the wrapping, if that works for your use-case, as long as you write it in a way that the compiler can use just a cheap `and`.  Wrapping of the whole integer type at a higher bit-position then doesn't matter.  (Especially if you use `unsigned` types, but atomics guarantee well-defined wrapping).

Comment: But actually here the problem is that between `int val = id.load();` and `while ...` some other thread can change the `id`. And in while loop between each iteration `id` also can be changed. But I need to make incrementation (with modulo) atomically in one operation. I wonder if isn't there any tool to do that in standard library?

Comment: Peter Cordes. Sorry for my earlier comment. It was concern to the "1 Answer", not to your comment. But due to your comment I fill like your suggestion with `maxId` to bealways power of 2 is the best solution in my case. But I need to learn little bit what exactly is "wrapping". Actually I need my `id` to be signed integer, so due to your comment it is worse scenario.

Comment: @pajczur I have updated my answer to provide more details. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: It looks to me that `newVal` does not need to be defined, and we could have a more concise form: `while (!id.compare_exchange_weak(val, (val + 1) % maxId) {}`